# Organizing a Flex Project for Team Use

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, code-organization, project-organization

I'm new to Flex/Actionscript/FlashBuilder, and I don't quite get all the organization concepts. Our teams project is primarily ASP.NET based, so it doesn't have a lot of Flex code. There hasn't really been a need for organization/reuse of common libraries. I'm adding a rather large component that has a lot of files, and I'd like to start keeping it organized for future developers.

As I see it, .NET has:

- Solution File: Points to a bunch of project files.
- Project File: Contains the actual code and dependencies.
- Namespace: Organizes code in a hierarchical manner.

In Flex, I want a hierarchy somewhat like this example:

- Car Dealership

  - Business Layer

    - Customer
    - Employee
  - UI Components

    - Advertisement
    - Window Tag
    - Car
  - Infrastructure

    - Payroll
    - Database
  - SWF Projects

    - InventoryViewer
    - CarFeatureViewer
    - CurrentFlyerViewer

In .NET, I could have a InventoryViewer Project file, and a Solution file that opened the InventoryViewer project file along with the Infrastructure.Database project file which it depends on. Alternatively, I could have a Solution file that just pointed to InventoryViewer if I didn't want to work on the Database project as well, but the dependency is still there. How does this translate to Flex code organization? I'm having a hard time telling the difference between packages, projects, and just a plain folder hierarchy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to mirror the solutions style view of VisualStudio, the best way to accomplish this is to create multiple **projects** into a 'solution' **workspace**.

There isn't a direct equivalent though, so don't worry about trying to see the hierarchy in the same way.

However, when you have a small workspace like this, you can build all projects in one pass, and keep the build times at a minimum.

Version control will only work well at the project level, so that can initially be a pain, instead of being able to checkout the solution in one go, you have to check out each project individually.

Regarding the difference between packages, projects and plain folder hierarchy:

- Project : A folder with Eclipse metadata (held in the folder and also in the parent workspace folder) that represents a project, projects can have multiple build targets, but only one is built at a time using the standard **Run** or **Debug** buttons, to build multiple targets in a single project, you have to use **Ant** or some other build tool.
- Packages : More closely related to what .net calls namespaces, however Flex has it's own concepts of namespaces, mostly relating to XML / MXML, but that's a fairly big topic so I'll avoid that. Packages must relate to the folders they are stored in, e.g.

.

```
package com.example.view {
    class SomeViewClass extends SomeFlexComponent {
    // .... etc
    }
}
```

This class would be stored in `src/com/example/view/SomeViewClass.as` - unlike C# class/package names and folders **must** match, or the compiler will throw an error.

I'm fairly sure I haven't covered everything here, so let me know if you need further clarification about any of this.

Comment: I guess I'm still unclear about what needs to be a Project. Using my fake project above as an example, would I make UIComponents a project, or would each of its children be its own project in the CarDealership/UIComponents folder? I assume the answer is "it depends", but on what I'm still not sure.

Comment: I'd probably say, make a project analogous to a VisualStudio Project, and make a Workspace where you'd create a Solution. UIComponents in your case would probably be a Flex/SWC Library project, that you then reference from another project (SWC files, are, roughly speaking, the flex equivalent to a DLL)

Answer (score 1):

If you vist some of the framework sites, and view the examples, you can see how they structure their applications.  Here is the source view for a program found on the Flex framework site of Mate.  You can download the source and open it in FlashBuilder to get a better feel.

http://mate.asfusion.com/assets/content/examples/intranet/srcview/

Personally, when I layout a Flex app directory structure, I break it up into "wings" based on views.  Of course there is a shared directory for things that are shared.  So for your example I would lay it out like this.

Car Dealership
*inventory
--views  (views pertaining to the inventory )
--components  (components pertaining to the inventory )
--events
--presenters
--services

The advantage of this is that it allows for modularity, so you don't have to load the entire application at once.